# WPF Xceed Toolkit can not enter text

Tags: wpf, xceed

when I use any of the UpDown controls from Xceed, I can't get them to accept text as I type. I've tried enabling AllowTextInput and using the PreviewTextInput function but the event doesn't fire. I can copy and paste numbers in there but nothing happens when I type.

Any ideas? I'm using Xceed 2.6.0, DotNet 4.5.2

Thanks

Comment: Default behavior of Xceed UpDown control is accept any input.
I think someone handle your PreviewKeyDown - Modifier.None - event on your visualtree.

Comment: You are correct sac1, I had a hidden event for previewKeyDown so that was causing the issue. 

Thanks for the help guys.